# How to plot a scatter plot for values in each category?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I have a dataset containing precipitation and wind speed data. I've categorized the wind speed (`max_ws`) into five equal categories using the `cut_number` function and the rainfall into four categories: 0 mm, 0.01 to 2.50 mm, 2.51 to 5.00 mm, 5.01 to 7.50 mm, and >7.51 mm.

I would like to create a plot that shows the amount of precipitation for each combination of `rain_category` and `ws_category`. So x-axis would be `rain_category`, y axis would be `ws_category` and data points in the scatter plot would represent `precipitation` column.

Here is the reproducible example of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(max_ws = c(2.4, 1.1, 0, 2.9, 3.8, 4.1, 3.9, 3.8, 
                                2.6, 3.8, 4.2, 2.1, 2.9, 1.5, 2, 2.2, 3.1, 2.9, 3.1, 4.3, 4.1, 
                                4.7, 3.1, 2.7, 5.7, 5.8, 3.8, 2.9, 0.3, 1.6, 0.8, 0, 1.9, 1.2, 
                                4.3, 0.9, 2.4, 3.7, 4.8, 4.5, 3.5, 0, 2.3, 3.2, 3.2, 5, 3.3, 
                                3.6, 2.4, 2.8, 4.7, 5.3, 4.4, 1.6, 5.3, 5.5, 4.6, 2.7, 3.5, 2.5, 
                                2.3, 3.5, 4.7, 3.8, 4.4, 2.8, 5.4, 3.3, 4.7, 4, 3.3, 3.1, 2, 
                                1.7, 2.7, 3.2, 3, 4.6, 4, 3.6, 3.2, 4.5, 3.8, 4.1, 3.3, 2, 3.2, 
                                4.1, 4.3, 4.6, 4.5, 3.9, 3.1, 3.9, 4.6, 3.7, 3.4, 4.9, 3.2, 3.8, 
                                4.6, 4, 1.9, 2.4, 3.3, 4.4, 3.4, 5.1, 4.6, 4.9, 3.4, 4, 3.6, 
                                4.9, 4, 5.3, 5.6, 4.4, 5.5, 5.9, 5.8, 3.9, 5.1, 3.8, 3.3, 4.8, 
                                3.7, 3.6, 4.3, 3, 4.8, 5.6, 4.3, 3, 4.8, 2.7, 4.4, 2.5, 4.5, 
                                2.8, 3.4, 4.7, 4.1, 4.2, 4.5, 4.9, 4.5, 2.9, 3.2, 3, 1.6, 2.4, 
                                3.3, 2.8, 3, 1.9, 3, 3.8, 3.1, 4.9, 5.3, 3.6, 3.8, 3.8, 2.5, 
                                3.5, 3.8, 4.2, 4.9, 4, 3.9, 4, 3.9, 5.3, 4.5, 4.5, 4.8, 3.3, 
                                2.7, 3.3, 3.5, 3.9, 4.8, 3.3, 2.9, 3, 4.5, 4.2, 3.6, 5.5, 6, 
                                4.4, 4.6, 4.7, 2.9, 3.7, 2.5, 4.1, 3.2, 4.6, 4.7, 2.9, 2.9, 1.7, 
                                3.6, 3.1, 3.6, 4.1, 3.4, 2.8, 3.3, 4.2, 3, 3.3, 2.4, 3.6, 2.8, 
                                2.9, 4.3, 4, 3, 2, 2.3, 3.7, 3.8, 4.4, 4.3, 4.7, 3.5, 2.6, 3.9, 
                                3.5, 2.8, 2.4, 3.7, 3.2, 2.5, 4.8, 3.7, 3.4, 2.9, 3.4, 2.5, 4, 
                                2.2, 3.7, 2.6, 2.6, 2.3, 2.6, 3.1, 2.5, 3.1, 3.2, 3.9, 3.1, 2, 
                                4.7, 2.3, 3.7, 3.3, 3.7, 3, 4.1, 3.6, 2.5, 3.3, 5.6, 4.5, 3.3, 
                                3.6, 3.7, 4, 3.9, 4.2, 3.3, 4.5, 2.9, 6.2, 3, 3.7, 2.1, 3.2, 
                                1.9, 3.3, 4, 3.6, 4.3, 3.7, 5.2, 3.9, 3.7, 2.9, 2.4, 3.8, 3.2, 
                                3.1, 2.5, 2.8, 3.2, 3.8, 3.2, 4.6, 3.3, 4.2, 3.9, 4.4, 4.4, 3.6, 
                                3, 4, 3.4, 4.3, 3.5, 2.5, 3.7, 3.3, 3.3, 1.2, 1.9, 2.9, 3.4, 
                                1.4, 2.7, 3, 4.2, 5, 2, 3.7, 8, 5.7, 1.8, 3.3, 3.8, 2.7, 4.5, 
                                3.6, 4.2, 5.2, 4.1, 4.9, 4.1, 2.9, 4.8, 4.9, 3.7, 2.7, 2.8, 5.2, 
                                3.9, 3, 2.8, 1.4, 2.9, 5.9, 5.2, 4.2, 4.3, 6, 5.6, 4.1, 5.5, 
                                4.2, 4.9, 5.7, 5.8), precipitation = c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.8, 0.6, 4.8, 9.8, 2.3, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       0.1, 2.3, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0.1, 4.3, 10.4, 3, 5.6, 
                                                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 3.3, 4.2, 2.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       1.7, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0.1, 0, 10, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       0, 0.6, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 
                                                                       0.1, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 1.9, 0, 8, 6, 0, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 0.3, 0, 1, 
                                                                       1.1, 1.5, 1.1, 4.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0, 0.3, 2.7, 0.7, 0, 0, 0, 3.8, 
                                                                       0, 0.1, 0, 0.8, 0, 0.1, 12.1, 4.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.1, 2.4, 0, 0.4, 
                                                                       0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 19, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4.8, 
                                                                       0.2, 2.9, 0.1, 1.6, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5.3, 0, 6, 0, 0, 2.5, 0.4, 
                                                                       4.4, 20.7, 6.1, 3.4, 2.8, 0, 0.2, 3.7, 0.6, 0, 0, 0, 4.2, 0, 
                                                                       0, 7.3, 10.3, 1, 4.3, 0.2, 4.2, 0.7, 4, 7.7, 3.1, 19.1, 2.6, 
                                                                       0.9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.2, 0.6, 1.9, 4.4, 0, 0, 0.4, 0.6, 0, 
                                                                       5.4, 2.6, 3.4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0.4, 0, 0, 13.9, 
                                                                       0, 0.1, 2, 1.9, 3.3, 1.5, 0, 0, 0, 5.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       0, 0, 0.1, 4.5, 0.9, 0.2, 3.9, 0, 0, 0, 0.7, 2, 0, 6.7, 1.4, 
                                                                       8.8, 10.9, 2, 3.8, 10.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 3.3, 0, 5.2, 1.9, 24.9, 2, 
                                                                       1.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0, 0, 10.5, 3.4, 0.2, 1.1, 2.1, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                       0, 0, 5.4, 0.8, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.3, 7.1, 0.2, 0.1, 3.9, 1.7, 3.2, 
                                                                       3.6, 0.4, 4.8, 0.3, 1, 0.9, 1.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3, 1, 0, 
                                                                       0, 0, 0, 0, 2.2, 0.1, 1.7, 0.3, 0, 0.7, 0, 1.9, 0.1, 3.2, 1.9, 
                                                                       1.4, 0, 0, 7.3, 8.7, 1.2, 5, 2.2, 0, 8.6, 3.7, 2.3, 5.1, 0.2, 
                                                                       0, 0, 3.5, 22, 1, 8.7, 2.6, 3.5, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 6.3, 7.8), ws_category = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                            4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                            5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                            5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                            5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                                            3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                                            3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                            5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                            4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                            3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                            4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                            5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                            4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                            3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
                                                                                                                                                            4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                            2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("[0,2.5]", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "(2.5,3.2]", "(3.2,3.8]", "(3.8,4.6]", "(4.6,11.6]"), class = "factor"), 
                     rain_category = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                                 4L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
                                                 3L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
                                                 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 
                                                 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 
                                                 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 1L), levels = c(">7.50", 
                                                                                                                 "0", "0.01 to 2.50", "2.51 to 5.00", "5.01 to 7.50"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                         -366L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

When I try to plot, I get only one data point in each category, but there are many data points in my data. What step am I missing?

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = rain_category, y = ws_category, fill = precipitation)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme_minimal() 
p
```

[image]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, but the community will be happy to help you solve problems that you run into writing your own code. What have you tried so far, and why didn’t it work?

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned the issue. I get only data point for each combination. Question updated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you want faceting? You can facet on the categorical variables and then plot the actual variables. `ggplot(df, aes(x = max_ws, y = precipitation)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(ws_category~rain_category)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By binning your data this way, all points are overlapping at each intersection of `ws_category` and `rain_category`. The whiteboard sketch resembles continuous data. If you want to keep the data labeled, but give a sense of the number of points in each bin on the grid, you can add random noise. This might lead to incorrect conclusions if it gives someone the impression that a point more to the right, within a bin, has a greater value.

**Edit** Following a question raised in the comments, added a plot of summarized data at the end.

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df, aes(x = rain_category, y = ws_category, color = precipitation)) +
  geom_point(size = 1,
             position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.25,
                                             jitter.height = 0.25)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Consider faceting, as suggested by @MrFlick in a comment. Each pair of categories is plotted on it's own, allowing you to plot points relative to each other using the actual measurements.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(precipitation, max_ws)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(ws_category ~ rain_category,
             scales = 'free')
```

[image]

### Summarize precipitation data for a plot

Before creating a plot, this calculates the average precipitation and counts the number of stations in each pairing of `ws_category` and `rain_category`. `fct_relevel()` is being used to change the order of the levels, putting `>7.50` at the end.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  summarise(avg_precipitation = mean(precipitation),
            n = n(),
            .by = c(ws_category, rain_category)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_relevel(rain_category, ">7.50", after = Inf), y = ws_category, label = n, fill = avg_precipitation)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(size = 10) +
  labs(x = 'Rain Category',
       y = 'WS Category',
       fill = 'Average Precipitation')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi @Ahsk. I edited the answer with a new chart that plots summarized data rather than individual observations. I hope this helps!